# DataFrame return slices of dataframe that a column value equal some value else 0 based on column of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'testid':(1,2,1,2,1,2),'Name':('apple','apple','melon','melon','orange','orange'), 'A': (1,2,10,20,5,5), 'B': (1,5,4,2,3,1)})
```

| testid | Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | apple | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | melon | 10 | 4 |
| 2 | melon | 20 | 2 |
| 1 | orange | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | orange | 5 | 1 |

I want to return a slice of this dataframe ( still a dataframe ) for every testid and Column A and B that if the corresponding apple value is larger than 1 then it returns the corresonding melon value, else return 0.
basically I want to get a DataFrame like this

| testid | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 2 |

how to achieve this? I tried apply() with lambda x:, but didn't find a way to put in the dataframe column into the lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work for you. Replace values corresponding to `melon` by according to values corresponding to `apple`.

```py
p = df.groupby(['testid','Name']).sum()
p.xs('melon', level=1).where(p.xs('apple', level=1)>1, 0).reset_index()
```

[image]